# C++ recursion returns nothing

Tags: c++, recursion

```
string go(string s, int& ind, node* cur,char &c)
{
    string f = "";
    if (cur->leftChild == NULL && cur->rightChild == NULL)
    {
        f = cur-> content;
    }
    else
    {
        if (s[ind] == 0x30)
        {
            ind++;
            go(s, ind, cur->leftChild,c);
        }
        else
        {
            ind++;
            go(s, ind, cur->rightChild,c);
        }

    }
    return f;// breakpoint here shows correct value 'e'
}
...
int main()
{
   string h = "";
   int ind = 0;
   string h = go(s, ind, &glob_root,c);
   cout << h << endl; // h is blank.
}
```

Turns out, that first time breakpoint on f hits, it shows value as 'e', what I want, but then it gets blank the following times it's hit.

if I change it to

```
string go(string s, int& ind, node* cur,char &c)
{
    if (cur->leftChild == NULL && cur->rightChild == NULL)
    {
       return cur-> content;
    }
    else
    {
        if (s[ind] == 0x30)
        {
            ind++;
            go(s, ind, cur->leftChild,c);
        }
        else
        {
            ind++;
            go(s, ind, cur->rightChild,c);
        }

    }

}
```

I get an access violation, since I have no return, If i add 
return "";
at the end, it just returns nothing, not 'e'

Any help appreciated

Comment: I don't know what your function is supposed to do, but you're ignoring return value of both recursive calls...

Comment: You should be writing something like `f = go(...)` (I guess).

Comment: it spans the tree according to directions in the string until it hits a leaf node, it shouldn't have output until that if(left == null && right == null) is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hit the `else` branch in your first chunk of code, then nothing ever modifies `f`, so of course it stays empty and that empty string is what you end up returning.

You *probably* want to `return go(...` or at least capture the return value and do *something* with it that involves `f` or returning it directly.